# ¿Cómo encuentro un párrafo específico con palabras repetidas y una palabra clave entre medio?

Tags: javascript, regex

Por ejemplo: Tengo un archivo de texto con lo siguiente:

```
<Task>
<nme>Hola mundo</nme>
<label>ffff</label>
.(más codigo)
.
</Task>

<Task>
<nme>aaaa</nme>
<label>bien</label>
.(más codigo)
.
</Task>

<Task>
<nme>Comandos</nme>
<label>bien</label>
.(más codigo)
.
</Task>

<Task>
<nme>Abrir puerta</nme>
<label>aaaa</label>
.(más codigo)
.
</Task>
```

Lo que deseo es obtener el código desde `<Task>` hasta `</Task>` con la palabra "Comandos" entre medio, es decir:

```
<Task>
<nme>Comandos</nme>
<label>bien</label>
.(más codigo)
.
</Task>
```

Mi intento de regex es el siguiente: `<Task>.*<nme>Comandos.*<\/Task>`

El problema es que ese regex me toma el código completo.
Espero que me puedan ayudar, gracias de antemano.

Comment: parsear un xml no parece demasiado lógico. Dado que es un texto estructurado, ¿por qué no parsearlo?

Comment: ¿Qué implementación de expresiones regulares quieres usar? ¿JavasScript, PHP, ...? Además agrega una breve descripción de tus esfuerzos de búsqueda como se sugiere en [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Podría decirte que con `/<Task>[^<]*(?:<(?!(?:\/Task|nme)>)[^<]*)*<nme>Comandos<\/nme>[^<]*(?:<(?!\/Task>)[^<]*)*<\/Task>/gi` lo solucionarías, pero es completamente ridículo usar regex para procesar un XML. Pensalo bien, estás ejecutando código JavaScript dentro de un navegador, una aplicación pensada específicamente para procesar documentos XML como HTML, pero no, querés procesarlo como si fuera texto?!?!?!?! Ridículo, no? Además, hay muchas formas en que una pequeña modificación en el XML lo haría fallar (podés leer muchas de las respuestas que hay en el sitio diciendo por qué no usa regex).

Es muy sencillo hacerlo de la forma correcta. Te muestro una forma.

Usando [`DOMParser.parseFromString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) se puede parsear un XML, transformándolo en un `XMLDocument` (que hereda métodos de `Document`). Y eso te permite usar los mismos selectores que si estuvieras tomando un elemento de la página web.

```js
//el string con un XML de la pregunta
const elStringDelXML = `
<Task>
<nme>Hola mundo</nme>
<label>ffff</label>
.(más codigo)
.
</Task>

<Task>
<nme>aaaa</nme>
<label>bien</label>
.(más codigo)
.
</Task>

<Task>
<nme>Comandos</nme>
<label>bien</label>
.(más codigo)
.
</Task>

<Task>
<nme>Abrir puerta</nme>
<label>aaaa</label>
.(más codigo)
.
</Task>`;

//El XML de la pregunta es inválido porque no tiene un elemento raíz
//todos los XML tienen que tener un tag (con cualquier nombre) que
//englobe a todo el documento. Lo llamo <Raiz> por ejemplo
let xmlCorregido = `<Raiz>${ elStringDelXML }</Raiz>`;

//DOMParser.parseFromString() genera un documento desde un string
//devuelve un documento, que es el que después usamos  para todo

let parser = new DOMParser(),
    doc = parser.parseFromString(xmlCorregido, 'application/xml');

//Y ahora usamos selectores como con cualquier documento HTML...

//Cada uno de los <Task>
for (let task of doc.querySelectorAll('\\Task')) {
    //El primer <nme>
    let nme = task.querySelector('\\nme');
    if (nme.innerHTML == 'Comandos') { //Si es <nme>Comandos</nme>
        //obtener todo el <Task> como texto
        let textoDelTask = task.outerHTML;
        console.log(textoDelTask);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

¿Esperas que siempre luego de `<Task>` venga `<nme>` ? Si es así, creo que esta regexp podría funcionarte.

```
/<Task>[\n\r]<nme>Comandos.*?<\/Task>/sg
```

Aquí puedes verla en funcionamiento: https://regex101.com/r/wKe24s/2

Por no tener más detalles sobre la implementación que haces, me limito a responder la pregunta. Espero sea de ayuda.